# Doxygen: Why does @name makes all following functions be considered as documented?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Consider this code documented by doxygen:

```
class A
{
public:
    /** func1 description */
    void func1();
    void func2();
};
```

Because I set `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED` to `YES` in my doxyfile, this reports `Warning: Member func2() (function) of class A is not documented.`. Fine

Now, if you add a `@name` tag to describe globally my two functions:

```
class A
{
public:

    /** @name A's standard functions */

    /** func1 description */
    void func1();
    void func2();
};
```

Warning does not show up anymore. But `func2` is still definitely undocumented.

Is there any option I did not set right? Is this a doxygen bug?

Comment: One could argue that you "documented" function 2 with your "name" comment block. The "name" attribute is defined as "header definition of a member group".

Comment: But in the generated html documentation `A's standard functions` just appears in the function list. `func2` is not even hyperlinked, there is really no description attached to this function.

Comment: Which version of doxygen were you using, with the current version (1.8.15) I get a message in both cases. With version 1.8.13 (the current version at the moment of the question) I get  only a message in the first case. I used a default Doxyfile.

Comment: @albert I dont recall what version I was using but I see the bug I reported by then is still open : https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6189

Comment: @jpo38 Thanks.  I cannot remember when the the extra warning was added, but I think that this solves the issue. I've noted this also with the mentioned github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Doxygen 1.8.13 bug. As proposed by Michaël Roy, migrating to Doxygen 1.8.15 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the doxygen documentation:

```
//!@{
//! one description for all members of this group 
//! (because DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC is YES in the config file)  <-- the interesting tidbit
#define A 1
#define B 2
void glob_func();
//!@}
```

Creation of the implicit documentation for functions inside the group is controlled by the global macro `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` in the configuration file.

In the doxygen GUI, you'll find `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` in the expert pane, topic "Project", near the bottom of the page.

Comment: I don't get what you intend here.

Comment: I added details in the answer.

Comment: The behavior described in the doxygen documentation _and_ marked by me is the cause of the issue.  Changing the `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` macro to NO will fix his problem.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` is already set to `NO` in my doxyfile, and I can see the issue with 1.8.13.

Comment: Cool. Glad you could resolve your issue.  I got here by chasing a somewhat similar problem in my doc - some groups would simply not print with the right fonts.  And it's good to know that at least the current version of doxygen works as documented.